# Viewpager in MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, android, mvvm, xamarin

I have five objects in the List as follows in my Viewmodel. I want this each object to be displayed in the each view in the `ViewPager`. Therefore, I have hardcoded with five fragments.

Is there a way to get the number of objects from the viewmodel and pass it to the view to make it modular rather than hard coded. I am using mvvm pattern.

Here is my project github: https://github.com/texas16/ViewPagerMVVM

**ViewModel class**

```
public RecyclerViewModel()
 {
    Items = new ObservableCollection<ListItem> {
        new ListItem { Title = "A" },
        new ListItem { Title = "B" },
        new ListItem { Title = "C" },
        new ListItem { Title = "D" },
        new ListItem { Title = "E" }
    };
 }
```

**View class**

```
var viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
if (viewPager != null)
 {
    var fragments = new List<MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo>
    {
      // hard coded
      new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 1", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
      new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 2", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
      new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 3", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
      new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 4", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
      new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 5", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment), typeof (RecyclerViewModel))
     };
   viewPager.Adapter = new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter(Activity, ChildFragmentManager, fragments);
 }
```

**ViewPager.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            local:tabGravity="center"
            local:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_recyclerview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        local:MvxBind="Refreshing IsRefreshing; RefreshCommand ReloadCommand">
        <MvxRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_recyclerviewexample"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; ItemClick ItemSelected" />
    </MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**listitem_recyclerviewexample.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/innerText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        local:MvxBind="Text Title" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way i see that possible with the way its structured is by making a new viewmodel before this part:

```
   var fragments = new List<MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo>
    {
      // hard coded
      ...
      ...
      ...
    };
```

so:

```
    var vm = new RecyclerViewModel();
    var fragments = new List<MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo>();
    for(int i = 0; i < vm.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        fragments.Add(new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView " + (i+1).ToString(), typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),typeof (RecyclerViewModel)));
    }

    viewPager.Adapter = new MvxFragmentPagerAdapter(Activity, ChildFragmentManager, fragments);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jesper Here is my project github: https://github.com/texas16/ViewPagerMVVM, I would be glad if you could guide me from this small project. When you run the project, you may need to click navigation drawer and click on ExampleViewPager to see my issue. I have upvoted your initial effort.